# Typescript type for Promise

Tags: typescript, knex.js

How best to type the below code without the `Promise: any` as I currently have it?

```
export const up = function(knex: knex, Promise: any): Promise<knex> {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.schema.createTable(
      'counters',
      (table: knex.TableBuilder): void => {
        table.increments('id').primary();
        table.integer('count');
      }
    ),
  ]);
};
```

I have tried `PromiseConstructor` but then there is an error with `Promise<knex>` being returned. Can't seem to find any documentation on typing `knex.js` migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should the return type be `Promise<knex>`?

`knex.schema.createTable` returns a `SchemaBuilder` which extends `ChainableInterface`, which ultimately extends `Bluebird<any>`, so the return type is `Promise<any[]>`.